# willRotateToInterfaceOrientation does not work when device is flat on a table

Tags: ios7, rotation, device

I am using this piece of code to detect a change in orientation and switch views in consequence:

```
-(void) willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {
if (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft) {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"PORTADA-PORTADAH" sender:self];
    }
else if (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"PORTADA-PORTADAH" sender:self];
    }
else if (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait) {
    nil;
    }
else if (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown) {
    nil;
    }
```

}

It works fine, but when the device is flat on a table, it doesn't work at all. It is just a question of lifting the device (an ipad) like 15 or 20 degrees, but my employer is not happy with this.

Any thoughts please?

Comment: What behaviour does the employer expect? You need to add more details. There is `UIDeviceOrientation`, there are hardware sensors you can use. But you need to provide more details.

Comment: Thank you Leo. It is expected that the change in orientation works equally when the device is flat on a table than when is lifted. What details do you need? This code is in each view controller with portrait orientation, what it does is perform the segue to the equivalent lanscape orientated view.

Comment: I am not sure this is even possible. When the device is flat, there is no way to know where the user is in relation to the device. Interface orientation changes occur when the gyroscope detects a difference in gravity vector.

Comment: Ok, then i guess is a question of convincing him... thanks again

Comment: It's always a problem to convince bosses of impossible requirements. ;-)

Comment: In this case he is family, so it will be easy. It was more a question of me trying to do better for him, he doesn't even noticed it. :)

Answer (score 0):

It will not call any of the 4 orientations when device is parallel with ground. or flat on table. It will call face up and face down orientations. by using previous orientations we need manage the origination using latest orientations of face up and face down.

Comment: I am sorry Madhu i dont understand your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Interface orientation in iOS is changed only when the gyroscope detects a difference in the gravity vector. When the device is laid flat, even if you rotate it around the y axis, there is no way to know where the user is in relation to the device. When the gravity vector changes, it is assumed that the user is parallel with that vector so it's easy to guess.

TL;DR - not really possible.